# How to add uids as a subkey? (firebase rtdb)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to add a subkey with a list of each user id that likes a post. Each method I used made the data come out pretty much similar to this [image]

Each time, undefined shows up and here's the code for it

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
var user = user.uid
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('Posts/' + '-Mc5Hrt0AN-lT8bc3G9t/'  + 'likes/' + user.uid)
      .push({
        user
      })
```

I've also tried formatting it multiple different ways in rtdb and firestore also to no avail. How do you store a plain list of uids in a key without having a title for the data (ex. movie: "Spiral") or something like "Spiral": boolean? Tried a few different solutions from SoF, YouTube and online but nothing was similar enough to what I wanted. I may not have worded it properly so I can clarify anything in the comments

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well yea, I was just stating that I tried multiple solutions and wasn't just asking after not trying. Gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'user' var is the UID of user itself and is a string. Try refactoring your code to this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const userID = user.uid
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('Posts/' + '-Mc5Hrt0AN-lT8bc3G9t/'  + 'likes/' + userID)
      .push({
        user
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: ahh, thank you, I kept getting undefined, learn something new everyday!